# Existence of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)< \infty$. $\;$Suppose $\phi: X \longrightarrow  [0,\infty) $ is measurable. Let $\epsilon>0$. 
  Prove that there exists a measurable subset $A$ of $X$ such that $\mu(X\setminus A) < \epsilon$ and $\phi$ is bounded on $A$.

Hint: for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define $A_n = \{x \in X \;| \; \phi(x) < n \}$. I don't know how to use this hint to prove the claim. 
 
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Further hint: $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n=X$,
$$
\mu(X)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n),
$$
which means that $\mu(X\setminus A_n)=\mu(X)-\mu(A_n)<\epsilon$ for all $n$ large enough.

Comment: What about the boundedness of $\phi$ in $A$ ?

Comment: It is bounded by construction: $\phi<n$ on $A_n$.

Comment: Sorry i can't follow those missing steps, can you please enlighten me?

Comment: You have some $N\ge 1$ s.t. $\mu(X\setminus A_N)<\epsilon$ and $\phi$ is bounded on $A_N$.

Comment: My bad! I get it now thank you very much!

Comment: Also i can't follow the logic to this part "$\mu(X\setminus A_n)=\mu(X)-\mu(A_n)<\epsilon$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: 1. $\mu(X\setminus A_n)=\mu(X)-\mu(A_n)$; 2. $\mu(A_n)$ converges to $\mu(X)$. So the difference must be small when $n$ is large.